# Add <br /> after every set of 5 images

Tags: php, image

Okay, I am currently using this:

```
<?php
$dirname = "cards/collecting/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach ($images as $image) {
$title = pathinfo($image);
echo '<img class="deck" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $title['filename'].'" title="'.$title['filename'].'">';
}
?>
```

This pulls a bunch of small images out of a folder and displays them. It works great, but I want there to be a 
 after each 5th image, so it doesn't stretch across the entire div in which the image are being shown. I'm unsure what I need to add to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a _count variable_ inside your foreach. Every five, close a `div`tag and open it again...

Comment: OR `array_chunk()` your array and use 2x foreach

Comment: y u no answer, instead of comment?

Comment: You could also use the CSS selector `nth-of-type()` and this way you can change how many images appear on each line without having to change your PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the index, you can write <br/> every time the index+1 is a multiple of 5: index 4, 9, 14, etc... Notice that I use $i=> in the foreach to get the value of $i.

```
<?php
$dirname = "cards/collecting/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach ($images as $i=>$image) {
    $title = pathinfo($image);
    echo '<img class="deck" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $title['filename'].'" title="'.$title['filename'].'">';
    if(($i+1)%5 == 0) echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I even tested a few odd sizes of image sets and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is use `array_chunk`.

> [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
>
> array array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
>
> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements

Code example:

```
$dirname = "cards/collecting/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
$grp = array_chunk($images, 5, true);
foreach ($grp as $items) {
    echo '<div class="item_grp">';
    foreach ($items as $image) {
        $title = pathinfo($image);
        echo '<img class="deck" src="'.$image.'" alt="'. $title['filename'].'" title="'.$title['filename'].'">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```